# Vim, how to move the cursor immediately and uniformely

Tags: vim, text-editor

Have you ever noticed (not only in Vim) that the cursor never change position uniformely after pressing movement keys but there's always an extra 0.5 second during which the cursor does not move?
Is there a way to prevent this behavior in Vim?

Comment: Never noticed it. There could be an abbreviation or mapping attempting to utilize your arrow keys or hjkl which is blocking further motion until it is sure you aren't typing the abbreviation.

Comment: It should be instant, unless you're editing something over SSH.

Comment: The cursor moves immediately, but the movement isn't uniform

Comment: If I press j the cursor moves immediately in the line below but then it stops for a 0.5s and then it moves again... like in any text editor

Comment: @Lorenzo - What exactly do you mean under "uniform movement"? I don't see anything wrong with the cursor.

Comment: I mean that immediately after pressing any movement key the cursor (not the mouse pointer) stuck for some instants

Comment: To notice what I'm saying keep pressed an arrow key... the cursor instantly starts moving in the right direction but there is a little while during which it is stationary...

Comment: @Lorenzo See my answer below, it's not related to the editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Took me some time to understand what you mean, but the behaviour you are describing is related to the keyboard repeat rate, more precisely the time before it starts repeating. That is OS related, has nothing to do with Vim or any other editor. Just look on the Internet how you can shorten the time for your OS, here's a link for Windows: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-keyboard-settings

Comment: Thanks! you understood exactly the problem. Now I reduced the repeat rate to the minimum... but is there no way to reduce it to 0?

Comment: That is really OS dependent. I've found some commands for the mac on the Internet, but didn't test them out. Anyway, I'm not sure if you'll really want to reduce it to 0, because you'll have to press really fast on the keys to not get doubles when typing :)

Comment: @Lorenzo - Wouldn't reducing it to zero cause it to paste an infinite number of characters as soon as you type one?